# repeating JavaScript function every second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two files, `index.php` and `table.php`. My `table.php` is included in `index.php` file in a div. For that, I did it as:

```
$("#tableloader").load('table.php')
```

My `table.php` changes every second. So to reflect it changes in the `index.php` file I tried:

```
function get_table() {
      $("#tableloader").load('table.php')
    }
    setTimeout( get_table, 1000 );
```

But it loads the table.php only once, not every second...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), which is just to launch a function at a specified time. **Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) for getting desired result.**

```
function get_table() {
    $("#tableloader").load('table.php')
}

window.setInterval(function(){
    get_table();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using 
setTimeout - calls a function after certain time. So, it will call your function once after 1 second.

You need to use:

`setInterval` - It will call your function after every 1 second.

Please have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).